# Why does the error 'invalid or unsupported image format' appear?

Tags: c, cs50

I've been working on CS50's pset3 and have been stuck on this one problem for awhile now. I copy most of my code from copy.c and referred to the walkthroughs to design my code as similar as possible but I can't seem to get the enlarged image to show. The code compiles fine and doesn't seem to have any problems when I run debug50 so I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this.

// Copies a BMP file

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <ctype.h>

    #include "bmp.h"

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

        // ensure proper usage
        if (argc != 4)
        {
            printf("Usage: ./resize n infile outfile");
            return 1;
        }

        // remember filenames
        int n = atoi(argv[1]);
        char *infile = argv[2];
        char *outfile = argv[3];

        if (n < 0 || n > 100)
        {
            printf("Usage: ./resize n infile outfile");
            return 1;
        }



        // open input file
        FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
        if (inptr == NULL)
        {
            printf("Could not open %s.\n", infile);
            return 2;
        }

        // open output file
        FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
        if (outptr == NULL)
        {
            fclose(inptr);
            printf("Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
            return 3;
        }

        // read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
        BITMAPFILEHEADER bf, bf_new;
        fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);

        // read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
        BITMAPINFOHEADER bi, bi_new;
        fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);

        // ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
        if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 ||
            bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
        {
            fclose(outptr);
            fclose(inptr);
            printf("Unsupported file format.\n");
            return 4;
        }

        bi_new = bi;
        //increase the size of biWidth for outfile
        bi_new.biWidth = bi.biWidth * n;
        //increase the size of biHeight for outfile
        bi_new.biHeight = bi.biHeight * n;
        // determine padding for scanlines
        int padding = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;
        int newpadding = (4 - (bi_new.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

        bi_new.biSizeImage = (bi_new.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) + newpadding) * abs(bi_new.biHeight);
        // write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
        fwrite(&bi_new, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

        bf_new = bf;
        bf_new.bfSize = bi_new.biSizeImage + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        // write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
        fwrite(&bf_new, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

        // iterate over infile's scanlines
        for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(bi.biHeight); i < biHeight; i++)
        {
            //multiply each scanline by n
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            {
                // iterate over pixels in scanline
                for (int k = 0; k < bi.biWidth; k++)
                {
                    //multiply each pixel in the width by n times
                    for (int l = 0; l < n; l++)
                    {
                        // temporary storage
                        RGBTRIPLE triple;

                        // read RGB triple from infile
                        fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

                        // write RGB triple to outfile
                        fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
                    }


                }
                // skip over padding, if any
                fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);

                //add padding to the outfile's scanline
                for (int m = 0; m < newpadding; m++)
                    {
                        fputc(0x00, outptr);
                    }
            }
        }

        // close infile
        fclose(inptr);

        // close outfile
        fclose(outptr);

        // success
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why `abs(bi.biHeight)`? If it ever turns negative you have integer overflow.

Comment: How is `bi.biSize != 40` a condition in identifying a bitmap file?

Comment: And who or what gives the message `'invalid or unsupported image format'`?

Comment: OT: regarding; *printf("Usage: ./resize n infile outfile");
            return 1;*   1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  2) the name of the executed file can be anything, just by renaming the executable.   Suggest:  `fprintf( stderr,  "Usage: %s expansionFactor infile outfile", argv[0] );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Note: `exit()` and EXIT_FAILURE are exposed via the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: OT: regarding: *fclose(inptr); printf("Could not open %s.\n", infile);*   see my prior comment about error messages to `stderr` rather than `stdout`.  Also, when the error message comes from a C library function should also output (to `stderr`) the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function`perror()` is made for this purpose.  also, any intervening statement changes the value of `errno`  Suggest: `perror( "fopen failed" ); fclose(inptr); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);` and `fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);`  always compare the returned value (which currently is not being checked at all) with the 3rd parameter.  If they differ, then the call to `fread()` failed.

Comment: regarding: `for (int l = 0; l < n; l++)
                    {
                        // temporary storage
                        RGBTRIPLE triple;

                        // read RGB triple from infile
                        fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

                        // write RGB triple to outfile
                        fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);`  This will copy successive `RGB triples` to the new file.  However should copy the SAME triple 'n' times

Comment: OT: regarding: `for (int m = 0; m < newpadding; m++)
                    {
                        fputc(0x00, outptr);
                    }`  Please consistently indent the code.  Strongly suggest each indent level is 4 SPACES,  I.E. do not use tabs

Comment: the 'planes | bits per pixel' needs to be paid attention to.  Because it can be 2bits for a black and white image. 8 bits for a gray scale image. 16 for a black and white with scaling/shading image.  24 bits for a RBG image.  32 bits for a RBG with transparency image.  These are all valid .bmp images with the same format identifer

Comment: @user3629249 reguarding the loop, i removed the `for (int l = 0; l < n; l++)` completely and added `fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), n, outptr)` which I thought would do it. However after i compile the program, I'm still receiving the same "invalid or unsupported image" prompt. As for the rest of the other comments, I'm still quite new to it and have yet to touch on the subject so I'm not too familiar with it. Perhaps the problem lies with my headers?

Answer (score 1):

Your way of enlarging the image is wrong. You now read pixels in the inner most loop. That won't work.

You must read a whole scanline, enlarge its pixels n times into a new scanline and then write that scanline n times.

I leave to you to change your code accordingly.

Comment: not quite correct.  Each pixel in the scanline must be repeated 'n' times, not the whole scanline enlarged 'n' times

Answer (score 0):

your question:

*Why does the error 'invalid or unsupported image format' appear*

It appears because when you try to display the image, the OS recognizes that the image file is not properly formatted.

[bmp image format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)